# Can I use chown to change permission of file on external bootable disk?

Tags: linux, permissions, google-compute-engine

I accidentally changed ownership of */usr/bin/sudo*.
Now I am getting

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

This is happening on google compute instance with linux OS. It seems like the only way to fix this is to mount the boot disk from another instance and fix the permissions.

Now I have mounted the disk from another instance. How can I change the permission of */usr/bin/sudo*?

I have very little knowledge on linux; if I use chown to change the permission will it be persisted on the disk?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can; and yes, it will be persisted unless Google Compute does something funny here.

You can set ownership with

```
chown 0:0 /usr/bin/sudo
```

The problem with changing ownership on an external disk that's usually mounted on some other system is that the UIDs (user id's) and GID (group id's) won't match, unless both systems are setup identically. But as long as you know the numerical id's, that's not a problem.

You can fix the setuid bit with `chmod`, if this is also broken.

Comment: the command will probably be `chown 0:0 /path/to/mountpoint/usr/bin/sudo` and then, `chmod u+s /path/to/mountpoint/usr/bin/sudo` to set the setuid bit if broken.
The root user will always have UID 0 and GID 0 on linux, so I think that won't be a problem here.